# Is there a way to communicate data from an iPhone app to Bluetooth chip using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, iphone, swift, bluetooth

I'm fairly new to JavaScript (I'm more comfortable with Swift) and I am not sure if there is a way to create a connection between an iPhone and a Bluetooth to create an event handler on the Bluetooth chip if certain conditions in the iPhone app are met. I am not even sure where to start so any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: So I assume you're using Cordova/PhoneGap to create the app? There's a bluetooth plugin [here](https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can. But this technology only works in the newest browsers (http://caniuse.com/#search=bluetooth thanks to [@yezzz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5752562/yezzz) comment). You need wait for all browser to accept this standard to use it publicly.

Check these out:

- https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/07/interact-with-ble-devices-on-the-web
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Bluetooth_API

Or if you using hybrid apps (like ReactNative, Cordova or PhoneGap) you **can** use bluetooth technology without problems!

- PhoneGap / Cordova: https://github.com/don/BluetoothSerial
- ReactNative: [Bluetooth in react-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32241386/bluetooth-in-react-native)

Comment: Thank you! The Mozilla link should be especially helpful!