# How to simulate Kontakt iBeacon unique identifier

Tags: react-native, ibeacon, kontakt.io

Besides the regular iBeacon uuid, major and minor fields, (and transmission strength), the Kontakt beacons have an extra 4 letter unique ID. This is tranmitted in the [Scan Response Packet] and is seen without the need to connect to the bluetooth device when the

See here [in the Kontak.io docs](https://support.kontakt.io/hc/en-gb/articles/206933735-Beacon-identifiers)

(Here's a question on Stack Overflow [about the definition of the Scan Response Packet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25159222/bluethooth-4-0-scan-response))  It has pointers to the definition. I presume the Kontakt unique ID is the Beacon ID field of the Scan Response Packet.

If I wish to emulate the broadcasting of a Kontakt beacon from my app on android (preferably react-native, for example using [react-native-beacon-simulator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-ibeacon-simulator)), what do I need to do?

Comment: The Beacon Simulator app in the app store does not have any way to set the scan response.

Comment: Also, nothing for setting the Scan Response in the [java Android timedBeaconSimulator class](https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library-reference/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/altbeacon/beacon/TimedBeaconSimulator.java) either. This class would enable me to simulate receiving the Kontakt beacons even in the emulator and debug on a remote machine. (I'm working with a macincloud)

Comment: Looks like these can be a good starting point:

[#32241386 bluetooth in RN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32241386/bluetooth-in-react-native) and 
[#2004388 writing charataristics in BLE Android 4.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20043388/working-with-ble-android-4-3-how-to-write-characteristics)

Comment: I think you have to see this link https://developer.kontakt.io/mobile/ios/managing/ you can get identifier of 4 letter in **Handling device discovery** events method.

Comment: could you write that as an answer and I'll mark it as such?